# Passing values to global variables

Tags: javascript, object, global-variables, parameter-passing

Does someone has a plausible explanation why javascript does not the pass the object literal as a value to the global variable that is passed via function parameter?

Do I overlook some fundamental rules?

```
(function(global) {
    var id = "3543a1354";
    global = {
        name: 'global',
        getId: function() {
            return id;
        }
    };
})(this.global = this.global || {})
```

So essentially the value of the parameter 'global' after executing the code is an empty object. Very strange: if setting a breakpoint for example on the last line and execute the object literal assignment in the console, then the value is correctly passed to 'global'.

BTW this would work as expected:

```
(function(global) {
    var id = "3543a1354";
    global.name = "global";
    global.getId = function() {
        return id;
    }
}(this.global = this.global || {}))
```

Comment: Parameter variables are always local variables, so they shadow the global variable with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

In both functions, `global` is a local variable, because it's a function parameter.

In the first case, you're creating a new object with the literal notation, and assigning this to the local variable. This has no effect on the variable that was used in the function call.

In the second case, you're modifying the properties of the object that the local variable refers to. This is the same object that the variable used in the function call refers to, so it's visible to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `this.global` to the function and inside the function `global` is the parameter which refers to the global `global`.

When you say,

```
global = {...}
```

you are now changing what `global` refers to. Since you have changed the reference, the global `global` is left unchanged and the local `global` refers to the newly assigned object.

In the second case,

```
global.name = "global";
global.getId = function () {..}
```

you are altering the local `global` object, which actually refers to the global `global`. So, you are indirectly changing global `global`. That is why, this mutates the global `global` and the first one didn't.

Comment: "and the local global refers to the newly assigned object." Not even within the function scope 'global' gets altered. You can check in the debugger

Comment: When you say `global`, do you mean local `global` or global `global`?

Comment: Damn now I know that was a bad idea to name the variable like that... I think what you want to say is that, within the function scope the value will be assigned to the local global. So you see alteration of the variable 'global' only within the function scope. When leaving the function scope the assignment did not affect the global variable 'global'. At least thats what I understood from your explanation

Comment: Ok. So in my first comment I was referring to the fact that the debugger does not indicate any alteration to variable 'global'. Regardless to the local or global reference ...

Comment: @crishushu No, local `global` would have got assigned a new object